# Merge CSS and JS files with only used code

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, audit

I have 18 CSS files and 20 JS files. After running in Chrome's Console Aufits-->Remove unused CSS rules. I can see some files have 93% of unused code. Something similar happens to the JS files. My website is only one html file and has no nested html files.

The ideal solution to my needs would be a software that scans my website and generates a single CSS file and a single JS file and only with the used code. If this tool does not exist, i can continue living with all the files but i need a tool to delete de unused code and leave just the used one.

Is there such a software?

Comment: You can always hire someone to check the files. Or you can do it yourself

Comment: @FlorinPop that's a very hard task to do manually

Answer (score 2):

**yes, you can!** use [uncss](https://www.npmjs.org/package/uncss) that's a pretty nice tool, you'll need to install node.js, [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [bower](http://bower.io/), git and install it by using npm.

then you just need to do a npm install -g uncss

that apply with any technology you can just use the dev node.js environment which is awesome!

Comment: perfect for CSS! any other similar software for the< JS files?

Comment: I'm not aware of any Js tool for it, but you can uglify the javascript take a look to https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify